# what is the danger of an application without State management

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management

I was new to the flutter so I build a full application without using state management, all my screens in the application built with the stateful widget 
what is the danger of that if many users used it?

Comment: there is no danger at all.

Answer (score 0):

You risk not being able to scale your code well. From passing data down the widget tree to passing data to screens etc., this will require a lot of lines which will lead to un-maintainable code. For small projects though, you don't really have to use state management libraries such as BLOC and Scoped Model.

Answer (score 0):

As the project scale, I believe you will have performance issues due to using setState() and without inherited widget your UI will re-render again every small change or action in your screen.
Also, Your code will get complicated as project scale because you are not separating your logic in a separate file (using bloc, provider or whatever), It will be a mess as UI and business changes.

Answer (score 0):

Most users won't know the internal architecture of your app unless they are good programmers themselves. But the goal of building applications is to attract users, and expand customer base. And this will require you or your company to add additional features in the future to accommodate their needs, and when you try to make even a subtle change to the source code, it will take more time and you will be prone to add new bugs to your application as your models and views are all mixed together.

Another reason is that you can't (as far as I know) test an app which doesn't have any type of state management.